# Making Boolean variable in dart. I don't know what I missed

Tags: dart

I want to make a variable to check a word that has contained some letters.
But I saw a null-safety error that says 'The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.'
I tried to find the miss, but can't find what I missed.

```
  List sampleText0 = ['ちゅうしじょう'];
  List yoonList = ['ゃ','ゅ','ょ','ャ','ュ','ョ'];

  bool YoonTest(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
      if(sampleText0[0].contains(yoonList[i])){
        print('Loop$i , True');
        return(true);
      } else if(sampleText0[0].contains(yoonList[i])!){
        print('Loop$i');
        return(false);
      } else {
        return(false);
      }
    }
  }
  
  if(YoonTest()){
    print('True');
  } else {
    print('False');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analyzer is complaining that there is no explicit return value if the `for` loop is never entered or if the loop is interrupted before reaching one of the `return` statements.  Given your code, that's logically impossible, but the analyzer apparently doesn't bother deducing that.

The code you've shown doesn't make logical sense anyway:

- The first two `if` conditions are equivalent.
- There's no point in looping if the loop body always `return`s (although I suspect that might be an artifact from your attempts to debug the problem).

You probably want something like:

```dart
var sampleText0 = ['ちゅうしじょう'];
var yoonList = ['ゃ', 'ゅ', 'ょ', 'ャ', 'ュ', 'ョ'];

bool YoonTest() {
  for (var character in yoonList) {
    if (sampleText0[0].contains(character)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```